# How to center longtable both horizontally and vertically

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, longtable

I have the following `longtable`, I want to center its content both vertically and horizontally, 
So far I've successed in centering it in one of them using the `array` package and `newcolumntype`

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}
```

This is the table :

```
\begin{longtable}{| C{0.2\textwidth} | C{0.25\textwidth} | C{0.25\textwidth} | C{0.25\textwidth} |}
            \hline
            \textbf{Méthode}    & \textbf{Description}  & \textbf{Points Forts}  & \textbf{Points faibles}  \\  \hline
            \textit{Scrum}  &   \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.4cm]
                \item Hiérarchisation des membres de 

            l'équipe.
            \item Développement progressif.
            \item Le travail est suivi quotidiennement.
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.4cm]
            \item Entièrement développé et 

            testé pour des 

            courtes itérations.
            \item Processus simple.
            \item Augmentation de 

            productivité.
            \item Responsabilité collective de 

            l'équipe.
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.4cm]
            \item Il est efficace pour les moyens et les petits projets.
            \item Si l'un des 

            membres de

            l'équipe quitte, 

            il peut avoir un 

            effet inverse sur le 

            développement 

            du projet.
        \end{itemize}
        \\  \hline  
        RUP (Rational Unified Process)  &   \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.4cm] 
            \item Promu par 

            rational.
            \item Le RUP est une 

            méthodologie et à 

            la fois un outil 

            prêt à l'emploi.
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.4cm]
            \item Itératif.
            \item Spécifie le dialogue entre les différents intervenants du 

            projet : les 

            plannings, les 

            prototypes... 
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.4cm]
            \item Coûteux à 

            personnaliser. 
        \end{itemize}
        \\  \hline
        XP (eXtreme Programming)    &   \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.4cm] 
            \item Ensemble de 

            "Best Practice" de 

            développement.
            \item S'adapte bien avec 

            des projets de 

            moins de 10 

            personnes.
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.4cm]
            \item Itératif 
            \item Simple à mettre en \oe{}uvre.  
            \item Concentre plus sur l'aspect technique : processus développement, prototypes, tests...     
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.4cm]
            \item Assez difficile dans sa mise en \oe{}uvre : quels intervenants, quels livrables ? 
        \end{itemize}
        \\  \hline                      
        2TUP 

        (Two Track 

        Unified Process)    &   \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.4cm] 
            \item S'articule autour de l'architecture.
            \item Suit un cycle de développement en Y.
            \item Vise des projets de toutes tailles.
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.4cm]
            \item Donne une place 

            à la technologie et 

            à la gestion du risque.
            \item Définit les profils des intervenants, 

            les plannings, 

            les livrables.
        \end{itemize}
        &   \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.4cm]
            \item N'exige pas de documents types. 
        \end{itemize}
        \\  \hline
        \caption{Comparaison des méthodologies de gestion de projet}
        \label{tb:comp_meth}
    \end{longtable}
```

How can I center the content vertically and horizontally?

Comment: Please tell us which document class you use and what the page and textblock dimensions are. Is the table supposed to fit on one page?

Comment: Instead of \centering you might try \hfil or \hfill between columns.  Without an MWE I can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to compile your code, but by I brief look I suspect that changing

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}
```

with

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}
```

will solve your problems